# Navigate views in a horizontal UIScrollView using VoiceOver

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, accessibility, voiceover

The Weather app hourly forecasts is a horizontally scrolling list of hours. When you use the app with VoiceOver enabled, you can swipe right to go from one hour to the next. When you reach the last one that's visible on screen, swiping to the right will scroll the list so that the next hour appears on screen, so all of the hours is accessible just by swiping.

I have a very similar setup with several `UIButton`s in a horizontal list inside a `UIScrollView`. It scrolls just like the hourly forecasts in Weather, but when using VoiceOver, upon reaching the last visible button, swiping to the right again doesn't reveal another button even though there are several more located off screen - it instead plays the "invalid gesture" or "no action" sound. If you want to get to the buttons that are off screen you have to swipe to the right with 3 fingers to move to another page. That shouldn't be necessary.

How can I obtain the same behavior as Weather, where swiping to the right will show the next button on screen, without having to swipe with 3 fingers to reveal more buttons?

Comment: Hey Jordan, did you ever figure this out? Im running into the same issue currently trying to side scroll with voiceover on